# How to animate the list item in a sequence using css3 keyframe animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am working on css3 animation for list items where each list item should animate one by one in a forward order with infinite loop. I tried few technique but could achieve the result. Any help would be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>content 1</li>
  <li>content 2</li>
  <li>content 3</li>
  <li>content 4</li>
</ul>
```

**Style**

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  color: green;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  animation: fade 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

li:nth-of(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
li:nth-of(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
li:nth-of(4) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    color: black;
    background-size: 0;
  }
  to {
    background-color: #1b385c;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/6cz7ayjn/9/)**

Comment: `li:nth-of(2)` - nth-of-what? There is no `:nth-of` pseudo class/selector as far as I am aware of.

Comment: The demo is already edited/updated.

Comment: Your animation has a duration of 1s, and you delay the start for each item by one second more … try an animation duration of 2s instead, and see how that changes the whole thing.

Comment: That doesn't help either [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/6cz7ayjn/14/) @misorude

Comment: Nah, I meant change the animation duration for _all_ to double that of the delay increments - http://jsfiddle.net/6cz7ayjn/16/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your animation keyframes are wrong, because 100% of your animation **is not** the time you animate that element, but the time you animate **all elements** (the full cycle which gets repeated). So, because you have 4 items, your animation needs to be:

```
            25%         50%         75%         100%
/* animation *************************************/
/************* animation *************************/
/************************* animation *************/
/************************************* animation */
```

Which means:

```css
 @keyframes fade {
  from {
    color: black;
  }
  12.5% { /* peak of animation */
    color: white;
    background-color: #1b385c;
  }
  25% { /* end of animation */
    color: black;
    background-color: gray;
  }
  to { 
    /* 75% stand still - same value as 25% and from */
  }
}
```

You don't actually need `to` here. I just put it there so I could comment on it. You can delete it.
And the `animation` has to be:

```
animation: fade 4s linear infinite;
```

(I remove the alternate: you're not reversing, because it's not symetrical. It's animated in 25% and the rest of 75% is still.)
See it working:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  color: green;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  animation: fade 4s linear infinite;
}

li:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
li:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
li:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
 @keyframes fade {
  from {
    color: black;
  }
  12.5% {
    color: white;
    background-color: #1b385c;
  }
  25% {
    color: black;
    background-color: gray;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>content 1</li>
  <li>content 2</li>
  <li>content 3</li>
  <li>content 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there any way I could able to increase the interval between each animation I tried and ended up with slower animation.[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/67wa5dre/1/)

Comment: @benjamin: of course. If you don't want them overlapping, just scale `4s` to whatever you want: i.e: `12s` and also scale the delays, using the same factor. If you want the animations to overlap (second animation starts when first animation is just finishing up, you can increase the `12.5%` and `25%`. Remember the next one starts at `25%`. So if you make them peak at `20%` and finish at `40%`, the next one will start just after the current one peaked, as it starts to go back. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/websiter/6cz7ayjn/24/

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
  <ul>
    <li>content 1</li>
    <li>content 2</li>
    <li>content 3</li>
    <li>content 4</li>
  </ul>
```

Css

```
    ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  li {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    color: green;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: fade 4s  infinite ;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }

  li:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }
  li:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }
  li:nth-of-type(4) {
    animation-delay: 3s;
  }
  @keyframes fade {
    0% {
      color: black;
    background-color: gray;
    }
    25% {
      background-color: #1b385c;
      color: white;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: gray;
      color: white;

    }
    100% {
        color: black;
        background-color: gray;
    }
  }
```